# SNMP - How to set a null or nothing value

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm working on some powershell scripts to set values for oid's.
One of the settings requires me to wipe out the current values first. Then set new ones. But I cannot seem to find the right syntax to make this work.

The syntax is DISPLAYSTRING but I'm having to use hex values to set them.
Here what the MIB says:

[image: MIB Viewer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can't. That object has a `MAX-ACCESS` of "read-write", meaning you can read from it and write to it. It is possible that the agent reports the object as "not existing" until you write to it (which is a bit naughty; that's what "read-create" is for). But that doesn't mean you can delete it or null it out. You cannot tell it not to have a value.

However, I believe you're misinterpreting the requirements. I suggest using the "No additional mapping" value of `0`; my interpretation of the description is that *this* is the "null mapping" it speaks of.

Alternatively, consult the documentation or vendor to find out how use of this particular MIB is intended.